# Is there a way to get GUID from a generic constraint type?

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

In the sample code below, the `Run<T>()` displays the values of GUID `IFoo` and `IFoo<T>` interfaces:

```
type
  IBar = interface
    ['{992E6597-42F1-40F8-B678-C4A86864B030}']
  end;

  IFoo = interface
    ['{0C589AF8-5727-4EAA-BB41-6D51D70B9D35}']
  end;

  IFoo<T> = interface(IFoo)
    ['{8FF54F6B-0896-4EA3-85F8-66BA70F9D2DA}']
  end;

  TTest = class
  public
    class procedure Run<T: IFoo>;
  end;

class procedure TTest.Run<T>;
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  IFoo_T_TypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
  IFooTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  IFoo_T_TypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  IFooTypeInfo    := LContext.GetType(TypeInfo(T)).BaseType.Handle;

  WriteLn('IFoo<T> GUID: ', GetTypeData(IFoo_T_TypeInfo).GUID.ToString);
  WriteLn('IFoo    GUID: ', GetTypeData(IFooTypeInfo).GUID.ToString);
  WriteLn('IBar    GUID: ', '?');
end;

begin
  TTest.Run<IFoo<IBar>>;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Is there a way to get `TGUID` or `PTypeInfo` from a generic constraint type, `IBar` interface in this case?

P.S.: I wouldn't like change the signature of `Run<T>()` to `Run<T, U>()` for just get the `IBar` GUID from U.

Comment: There is no way to access a Generic's constraints in code. Besides, there is nothing in this code that is using `IBar` as a constraint anyway.  `T` in `Run()` is `IFoo<IBar>`, you will have to retrieve that typename as a string from `T`'s RTTI and parse it to extract `IBar` from it.

Comment: You mean the only way would be to search for String like: ``TRttiContext.Create.FindType('MyUnit.IBar');``?

Comment: FWIW, it is not a good idea to give a generic interface a GUID. All instantiations of the interface will have the same GUID, so it is not unique and won't work anyway. Either use a non-generic interface or omit the GUID, depedending on your needs.

Comment: @Rudy Bad advice. There are certainly scenarios where generic interfaces should have GUIDs. Have a read of the spring4d source code.

Comment: @David: That Spring4D supposedly does it still doesn't mean it is a good idea to have a GUID on a generic interface. So I maintain my advice that generic interfaces should not have a GUID. But if you know a scenario where it makes sense, I'd like to know about it (but not something vague like: see the sources of a certain library).

Comment: @David: the purpose of GUIDs on interfaces is to uniquely identify them, i.e. to make operators like `as` and functions like `Supports()` work. Since *every* instantiation of the generic would get the same GUID, that doesn't make sense, since these are **not unique**. This advice is not just from me, it was also the advice from people like Barry Kelly and, IIRC, Danny Thorpe. Now if the compiler would generate a new GUID for each instantiation, things would work again. But it doesn't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Read the source to spring4d to learn about scenarios where GUIDs on generic interfaces are used appropriately. Or do you already know everything? I used to share your viewpoint until Stefan put me right.

Comment: The point of guids on generic collection types in Spring4D is to internally be able to use Supports where it is ensured that in a class of `something<T>` it only tries to use it on some `interface<T>` and not `interface<U>`. It does not mean that a user of the library should use this and do something like `if Supports(bananas, IList<TApple>, apples) then`.

Comment: Also when injecting generic interfaces with the DI container they need to have guids to let the container get them from the implementing class it created because it is typically the case that the implementing class is also a generic and that it is rather uncommon to implement something like `X = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo<A>, IFoo<B>)`- yes, possible to write that code but that of course would not work as `IFoo<A>` and `IFoo<B>` would share the same guid.

Comment: FWIW the interface table of a class also has the typeinfo of the interface stored since I think XE2 or so - so in fact one could do a Supports implementation that uses a PTypeInfo instead of a TGuid. But that again would not work across modules as typeinfo would be different (which is the point of guids)

Comment: @David: Stefan's explanation is better. Your advice "Read the source to spring4d" is exactly what I didn't want to see, as I said: "(but not something vague like: see the sources of a certain library)".

Comment: @Stefan: I don't understand this: "*The point of guids on generic collection types in Spring4D is to internally be able to use Supports where it is ensured that in a class of something<T> it only tries to use it on some interface<T> and not interface<U>*". I assume you want to be able to distinguish between completely different interfaces, e.g. IBla<T> and IFoo<T>. That should work. But distinguishing between IBla<T> and IBla<U>, where T and U are different types, would not work.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Exactly. The generic type parameter always matches. For example the base type `TEnumerable<T>` has a method `ToArray` which uses its enumerator to put out an array. Well due to the nature of an enumerator you cannot get the count before and have to either grow the array one by one of some different strategy. However it has an optimization for `if Supports(Self, ICollection<T>, coll) then`. That avoids having to reimplement/override ToArray in any inheriting class that can do this any better but put this optimized path in the base class already.

Comment: @Rudy I'm not an expert of this subject which is why I didn't try to say more. Never a good idea to try to talk on subjects that you aren't expert in.

Comment: @david: Yeah, I know. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting typeinfo/RTTI from generic type parameters is a bit tricky but not completely impossible.

Here is some example code how to do that (I am using the RTTI extensions from the Spring.Reflections unit).

```
uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils,
  Spring.Reflection;

type
  TTest = class
  public
    class procedure Run<T: IFoo>;
  end;

class procedure TTest.Run<T>;
var
  LType, LType2: TRttiType;
begin
  LType := TType.GetType(TypeInfo(T));
  if LType.IsInterface then
  begin
    if LType.AsInterface.HasGuid then
      Writeln(LType.Name, ' GUID: ', LType.AsInterface.GUID.ToString);
    LType2 := LType.BaseType;
    while Assigned(LType2) and (LType2.Handle <> TypeInfo(IInterface)) do
    begin
      if LType2.AsInterface.HasGuid then
        Writeln(LType2.Name, ' GUID: ', LType2.AsInterface.GUID.ToString);
      LType2 := LType2.BaseType;
    end;

    if LType.IsGenericType then
    begin
      for LType2 in LType.GetGenericArguments do
        if Assigned(LType2) and LType2.IsInterface then
          Writeln(LType2.Name, ' GUID: ', LType2.AsInterface.GUID.ToString);
    end;
  end
end;

var
  bar: IBar;
begin
  bar := TBar.Create; // cause RTTI for IBar to be generated to look it up later
  TTest.Run<IFoo<IBar>>;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The check if the type is generic is done via string parsing of the type name. If it contains angle brackets it is a generic type. It then extracts the type names which are always full qualified type names which makes it possible to look them up.

However there is one gotcha to keep in mind. You can only look those up when the type info for that type was generated in some other context than just the generic type parameter. That is why in that sample I made a simple TBar class that implements IBar and created some instance to prevent the linker to strip that class (and the necessary RTTI). In real code this is less of an issue because you typically have some implementations of that interface. Also for this example to work you need to put the interface into their own unit because lookup by full qualified name does not work for types in the dpr.

Comment: I tried to make a MCVE and I did not pay attention to compiler optimizations. In my real scenario my types are public, and your answer worked perfectly. Thanks!